# Is there a straightforward way to convert a date to long form text output?

Tags: r, date

For example, if I have a `Date` (or `POSIXct`) object and it's in the format "2016-01-01" is there a simple way to convert it to: "January 1, 2016" (or something like it) without writing my own custom function?

Comment: `?format` or `?strftime`.

Comment: x <- "2016-01-01" ; strftime(x, format = "%B %d %Y")

Comment: Downvote if you want, but none of my Googling returned "strftime" as a possibility (instead I kept going down lubridate black holes) so thanks.

Comment: To avoid future black holes, it's often useful to check the docs for the classes, e.g., `?Date` and `?POSIXct`. The `See Also` sections of these point you to `strptime` and `format.Date`.

Comment: @jbaums: or `?DateTimeClasses` in the case of date-time classes.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for what you are asking.

```
date <- "2016-01-01"

format.Date(date, format = "%B %d, %Y")

[1] "January 01, 2016"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lubridate has a set of functions which extract information from a data-time object, see the ["Setting and Extracting information" section of the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html). If you want to form an output string you can paste the outputs together.

For example

```
library(lubridate)
date <- ymd("2016-01-01")
paste0(month(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE), " ", day(date), ", ", year(date))
[1] "January 1, 2016"
```

It's more code but I personally find the functions easier to remember.

Comment: Hah, I knew about the "month" function, but for some reason I hadn't discovered that it had other arguments. I feel dumb.